# Root composer.json requires specific version

Tags: php, laravel

Running this command to install a package:

composer require digitalcloud/multilingual-nova

It shows some issues:

```
   Problem 1
        - Root composer.json requires digitalcloud/multilingual-nova ^3.0 -> satisfiable by digitalcloud/multilingual-nova[v3.0.0].
        - digitalcloud/multilingual-nova v3.0.0 requires spatie/laravel-translatable ^4.0 -> found spatie/laravel-translatable[4.0.0, ..., 4.6.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.0).
```

Do you know how to properly fix? Thanks!

Comment: please post your `composer.json` I think you'll find something telling you have to use v6.0 of `spatie/laravel-translatable`, try to remove this condition and try again

Comment: `digitalcloud/multilingual-nova` requires `spatie/laravel-translatable 4.0`, but is not compatible with the `spatie/laravel-translatable 6.0` that you're apparently requiring somewhere. `multilingual-nova` hasn't been updated since Dec 30, 2021, long after `laravel-translatable` went up to 5.0. Either you'll need to downgrade your version of `laravel-translatable`, contact the devs of `multilingual-nova` to upgrade, or find another package.